# electron-packager - exclude ffmpeg from final build

Tags: ffmpeg, electron, electron-packager

I am working on electron windows desktop app. I would like to make my build little bit smaller. I noticed that electron-packager add ffmpeg and other files into final build, my question is, is there possibility to make build without ffmpeg possibly without other unnecessary files (if there are any).

My build command look like this:

```
"electron-packager . hiss_xread --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --appCopyright=\"Copyright 2020 Tom Ravn, all rights reserved.\" --icon=src/favicon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Hiss xRead\""
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @SwapnilPatwa unfortunately not. I will update this question in case I will find something, but for now I am not in electron world, but it can change anytime. Have a great day.

Comment: Based on my studies, getting rid of ffmpeg is not possible as it is required by chromium to work. The FFMPEG is GPL licensed that's why I was searching for a way to remove it. Anyway Thanks much for quick reply. Have a great day ahead.